# Django ajax how to get object image src link?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, ajax

I am implementing ajax in my list views page. Now I am facing problems for rendering image. How to get my image src link of each object ?

views.py:

```
class PostJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        upper = kwargs.get('num_posts')
        lower = upper - 1 
        posts = list(Blog.objects.values('id','title','body','blog_header_image')[lower:upper])
        posts_size = len(Blog.objects.filter(is_published='published'))
        max_size = True if upper >= posts_size else False
        return JsonResponse({'data':posts,'max': max_size},safe=False)
```

**.html**

```
  <div class="card mb-4" id="card mb-4"></div>



    <script>
    
    
    const postsBox = document.getElementById('card mb-4')
    console.log(postsBox)
    const spinnerBox = document.getElementById('spinner-box')
    const loadBtn = document.getElementById('load-btn')
    const loadBox = document.getElementById('loading-box')
    let visible = 1 
    
    const handleGetData = () => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: `/posts-json/${visible}/`,
            success: function(response){
                maxSize = response.max
                const data = response.data
                spinnerBox.classList.remove('not-visible')
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    spinnerBox.classList.add('not-visible')
                    data.map(post=>{
                        console.log(post.id)
                        postsBox.innerHTML += `<img class="img-fluid rounded"  style="max-height:1000px;max-width:1200px;" src="" alt="..." />`
                    })
                    if(maxSize){
                        console.log('done')
                        loadBox.innerHTML = "<h4>No more posts to load</h4>"
                    }
                }, 500)
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    }
    
    handleGetData()
    
    loadBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        visible += 3
        handleGetData()
    })
    
    
    </script>
```

How to get object href so user can click an view the details page? also how to render image url?

Comment: Haven't you tried:  ``postsBox.innerHTML += "<img ... src="+post.blog_header_image+"...</>"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting image url by using `values()` in django you will not get the path of your image to get path you need to prepend your `MEDIA_URL` for each object like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

posts = list(Blog.objects.values('id','title','body','blog_header_image')[lower:upper])
for post in posts:
     post['blog_header_image'] = settings.MEDIA_URL + post['blog_header_image']
```

and then in your javascript you can access the image like this:

```
postsBox.innerHTML += "<img ... src="+post.blog_header_image+"</>"
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
 posts = list(Blog.objects.all()[lower:upper])
 data = list()
 for post in posts:
     data.append({'id': post.id, 'title': post.title, 'image_url': post.blog_header_image.url})

 return JsonResponse({'data':data,'max': max_size},safe=False)
```

And then in javascript:

```
 postsBox.innerHTML += "<img ... src="+post.image_url+"</>"
```

Answer (score 0):

To render image URLs and object `'MEDIA_URL'` links for each object in your list view page using AJAX, you need to modify your server-side code to include these details in the JSON response. Here's how you can modify your `views.py` and JavaScript code:

In your `views.py` file, modify the `Blog.objects.values()` method to include the `href` and `image_url` fields:

```py
from django.conf import settings

class PostJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        upper = kwargs.get('num_posts')
        lower = upper - 1 
        posts = Blog.objects.filter(is_published='published')[lower:upper]
        data = []
        for post in posts:
            post_data = {
                'id': post.id,
                'title': post.title,
                'body': post.body,
                'blog_header_image': post.blog_header_image.url if post.blog_header_image else '',
                'href': settings.MEDIA_URL  
            }
            data.append(post_data)
        max_size = upper >= posts.count()
        return JsonResponse({'data': data, 'max': max_size}, safe=False)
```

Now, in your JavaScript code, you can use the `href` and `blog_header_image` fields to render the details page link and the image URL respectively:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `/posts-json/${visible}/`,
    success: function(response){
        maxSize = response.max
        const data = response.data
        spinnerBox.classList.remove('not-visible')
        setTimeout(()=>{
            spinnerBox.classList.add('not-visible')
            data.map(post=>{
                postsBox.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                        <a href="${post.href}">
                            <img class="img-fluid rounded" style="max-height:1000px;max-width:1200px;" src="${post.blog_header_image}" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                `;
            })
            if(maxSize){
                loadBox.innerHTML = "<h4>No more posts to load</h4>"
            }
        }, 500)
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

This will render a clickable image for each post, with the image URL and href link derived from the JSON response data.

Comment: You've already been told that these AI-generated answers are unacceptable...